# Can I download and parse a large file with RestKit?

Tags: ios, rest, restkit, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

I have to download thousands or millions of hotposts from a web service and store them locally in core data. The json response or file is about 20 or 30 MB, so download will take time. I guess mapping and store it in core data will also take time time.
Can I do it in restkit? or has been designed just for reasonable size responses?
I see I can track progress when downloading a large file, even I see I can know when mapping starts or finishes: http://restkit.org/api/latest/Protocols/RKMapperOperationDelegate.html
Probably I can also encapsulate the core data operation to avoid blocking the UI.
What do you think? Do you think is this feasible? Or should I select a more manual approach? I would like to know your opinion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not encapsulation or threading, it's memory usage.

For a start, thousands or millions of 'hot posts' are likely to cause you issues on a mobile device. You should usually be using a web service that allows you to obtain a filtered set of content. If you don't have that already, consider creating it (possibly by uploading the data to a service like Parse.com).

RestKit isn't designed to use a streaming parser, so the full JSON will need to be deserialised into memory before it can be processed. You can try it, but I suspect the mobile device will be unhappy if the JSON is 20 / 30 MB.

So, create a nice web service or use a streaming parser and process the results yourself (which, could technically be done using RestKit mapping operations).

Comment: Thanks for reply. That's exactly what I think, but my customer (who creates the web server) it's what he wants. So, basically, I want to know if I can do it. For instance, how can I combine request operations? I mean, create an operation that sends 2 or 3 requests following a logic, depending on first request response. Mmm... I think I will open a new question in stackoverflow. BTW, are requests and mapping 2 different nsoperations in serial? Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: The mapping operations would be added to a queue so you can set how many run concurrently (and block the parsing if the operations aren't running fast enough)...